# Visual Studio Code Cobol Extension - Code Navigation using F12

Tags: visual-studio-code, definition, cobol

I'm using this Cobol extension for Visual Studio Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bitlang.cobol

It works very well and I've got it all set up. The only problem remaining is that I want to use the functionality to press F12 to jump to a definition in my code, so if I click "styledocument.sd" in the code of a program and press F12 it's supposed to open the styledocument file, but all the editor does is say "No definitions found for "styledocument"." Our lead developer says the functionality used to be there and it just vanished at some point for no reason.

Is there any way to get this functionality back? It'd be really useful, I'm very new at programming and this would be a godsend as it'd help me find my way around the code at a reasonable pace, as everything seems really difficult right now.

Thank you everyone for your replies!

Comment: I think this may be out-of-scope for StackOverflow. In any case I suggest to check the documentation (keyword "metadata" may help) at https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol and if you can't figure it out create an issue there. An in any case you can choose to downgrade to an older version if it worked there.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me!

Comment: Any update on this? You may want to either self-answer your question (Q+A-Style) providing a good explanation if you think it matches this SO site, or otherwise remove the question.

Comment: or link back to the original issue: https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol/issues/248

Comment: I think it's best to just link you to the issue I opened on Github: https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol/issues/248 
I got great help and an explanation over there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit late but I believe it can still be useful :)

To make copybook work, you have to :

- have a folder opened in your IDE
- add the directories to search in, in the setting `coboleditor.copybookdirs` (path starts from the root of your folder)
- Specify files extensions of your copybooks by modifying the setting `coboleditor.copybookexts`
- set the setting `coboleditor.parse_copybooks_for_references` to true

Now your copybooks should work.

But if you call without the `COPY` instruction, this won't work. except if you change this setting :

- `coboleditor.scan_comments_for_hints` to true

This setting will allow VSCode to read some specific comments.

`*> @source-dependency fileName`

For each file called with an other method as `COPY`, you'll have to put the comment above anywhere in the code to activate copybook on the specified file.